# SparkSQL — collect_set and sort_array does not sort integer column properly

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I want to generate a sorted, collected set in SparkSQL, like so:

```
spark.sql("SELECT id, col_2, sort_array(collect_set(value)) AS collected
           FROM my_table GROUP BY id, col_2").show()
```

where **`value`** is an `integer`.

**But it fails to sort the array in proper numeric order** — and does something rather ad hoc (sort on beginning of the first number in the value instead? Is sort_array operating on a string?).

So instead of:

```
+----+-------+------------+                                              
| id | col_2 | collected  |
+----+-------+------------+
| 1  |   2   |  [456,1234]|
+----+-------+------------+
```

I get:

```
+----+-------+------------+                                              
| id | col_2 | collected  |
+----+-------+------------+
| 1  |   2   |  [1234,456]|
+----+-------+------------+
```

---

**EDIT:**

Looking at what `spark.sql(…)` returns it is obvious that this query returns strings instead:

```
DataFrame[id: string, col_2: string, collected: array<string>]
```

How can that be when the original dataframe is all `integers`.

---

**EDIT 2:**

This seems to be a problem related to `pyspark`, as I'm not experiencing the problem with `spark-shell` and writing the same stuff in `scala`

Comment: I'm wondering if there were some string, blank, or null statements that ended up forcing the data type to change to string.  Here's a quick example where I had converted various columns to long (from string) and then performed a similar `sort_array(collect_set(...))` command which resulted in `collected` being sorted correctly.  https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/dennyglee/databricks/blob/ed18abfa25439bf604bba7a02956052bba0d654f/notebooks/Users/denny@databricks.com/examples/SparkSQL%20-%20collect_set%20and%20sort_array.html

Answer (score 3):

I tested with Apache Spark 2.0.0.

It works for me.  To make sure I tested with data `[(1, 2, 1234), (1, 2, 456)]` and `[(1, 2, 456), (1, 2, 1234)]`.  The result is same.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 1234), (1, 2, 456)], ['id', 'col_2', 'value'])
# test with reversed order, too
#df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 456), (1, 2, 1234)], ['id', 'col_2', 'value'])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")


sqlContext.sql("SELECT id, col_2, sort_array(collect_set(value)) AS collected FROM my_table GROUP BY id, col_2").show()
```

Result

```
+---+-----+-----------+
| id|col_2|  collected|
+---+-----+-----------+
|  1|    2|[456, 1234]|
+---+-----+-----------+
```

Some observations

- when a value is None it appears as null e.g. [null, 456, 1234]
- when there is a string value, Spark throws error "TypeError: Can not merge type LongType and StringType"

I think the problem is not the SQL but in the earlier steps where DataFrame  was created.